# sql query return the rows without common attributes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new with sql ans ms-access.
So, i have table tab1, with columns
[id, decscription, number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGuJR.jpg)
i want to make a query that returns the id of the rows without common description and number.
The desirable output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVVFz.jpg)

I have tried

```
SELECT  id
FROM tab1
GROUP BY  id, description, Number HAVING COUNT(*)=1;
```

but returns logical error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return rows that are unique, you can do:

```
select *
from tab1
where not exists (select 1
                  from tab1 as t
                  where tab1.description = t.description and tab1.number = t.number and
                        tab1.id <> t.id
                 );
```

You can also do this using aggregation.  To get the `id`:

```
select max(id)
from tab1
group by description, number
having min(id) = max(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id
FROM tab1
GROUP BY  description, Number HAVING COUNT(*)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, perhaps:

```
SELECT 
    id, description, Count(*) As Number
FROM 
    tab1
GROUP BY
    id, description
```